# How to fix: Error in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : input/output error

Tags: r, microsoft-r

I'm currently running some R code using the RevoScaleR package for Microsoft R server. I'm getting the following error.

> Error in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : 
>     input/output error, but BxlServer is still alive. Last system error: 0

I've used the `.rxNumRows` function in a different part in the R code and the same error shows.

Below is the code snippet that produces the above error.

```
input_xdf <- 'yellow_tripdata_2016_manhattan.xdf'
mht_xdf <- RxXdfData(input_xdf)
rxDataStep(nyc_xdf, mht_xdf, 
            rowSelection = (
             passenger_count > 0 &
             trip_distance >= 0 & trip_distance < 30 &
             trip_duration > 0 & trip_duration < 60*60*24 &
             str_detect(pickup_borough, 'Manhattan') &
             str_detect(dropoff_borough, 'Manhattan') &
             !is.na(pickup_nb) &
             !is.na(dropoff_nb) &
             fare_amount > 0), 
             transformPackages = "stringr",
             varsToDrop = c ('extra', 'mta_tax', 'improvement_surcharge', 'total_amount', 'pickup_borough', 'dropoff_borough', 'pickup_nhood', 'dropoff_nhood'),
             overwrite = TRUE)
mht_sample_df <- rxDataStep(mht_xdf, rowSelection = (u < .01), 
                            transforms = list(u = runif(.rxNumRows)))
```